# How to retrieve record from Eloquent Model?

Tags: laravel, database, eloquent

This sounds stupid but I can't find a way to retrieve a record from eloquent model **`Gallery.php`**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Gallery extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['text'];
}
```

Calling from a Route in **`web.php`**:

```
$data = Gallery::with('id', '=', 1)->get();
```

throws this error in `laravel.log`:

```
local.ERROR: Call to undefined relationship [id] on model [App\Models\Gallery]. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\RelationNotFoundException(code: 0): Call to undefined relationship [id] on model [App\\Models\\Gallery]. at /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/strong-moebel.art/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/RelationNotFoundException.php:35)
```

The only thing that works is:

```
$data = Gallery::all();
```

Comment: You most likely meant `Gallery::where('id', '=', 1)->get();` or even `Gallery::find(1);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The with() method at:

```
Gallery::with
```

Is used to refer to relationship with another model.
If you are looking to get data from just the Gallery model change with() to where() as below:

```
$data = Gallery::where('id', '=', 1)->get();
```

This will return a collection (think of it as an object containing an array of the results).

If you're trying to access additional data from a related model you will need to setup the relationships as per the Laravel documentation.

If you want just the instance of Gallery related to that id, you can get it with

```
$gallery = Gallery::where('id', '=', 1)->first();
// or
$gallery = Gallery::find(1);
```

Comment: This seems to be the right way but in my case it throws:

`local.ERROR: Illuminate\Log\LogManager::info(): Argument #2 ($context) must be of type array, bool given`.

Any idea why?

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov that is another error unrelated to your current post, i suggest you open another question for it with the relevant details to it like where is the code calling for `Log::info('...')`